# how to implement AutoCompleteTextView inside DialogFragment

Tags: android

i have null pointer exception when put this inside DialogFragment in onCreateView method

```
 AutoCompleteTextView med =(AutoCompleteTextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.new_autoCompleteT);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
 med.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: 06-16 08:37:28.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 08:37:28.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2677): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 08:37:28.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2677):  at rajab.apps.ViewPatient.visittFrag$TaskDetailFragment.onCreateView(visittFrag.java:382)
06-16 08:37:28.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2677):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to retrieve a `View` from the associated `Activity`. You should check the call to `getActivity()`, maybe it's returning null because the activity it hasn't attached yet. Check the `onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29):

```
Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving views or restoring state.
```